# How to work around Bash for loop not exiting when a subcommand errors?

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a for-loop in a shell script a la:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u
set -e
for l in sh rb py php java cs; do
  (cd $l; ./run-tests.sh)
done
```

The intent is to have the for-loop die in a fire when any one of the sub-commands similarly errors out.

Now, I have a work-around in place: `(cd $l; ./run-tests.sh) || die "Message here"` along with a suitable definition of `die`.  However, I'm genuinely curious why the for-loop doesn't self-terminate per the expectation set by the "set -e" command?  Ideally I'd like to not special-case every for-loop like that.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `set -e` does not exit immediately if `./run-test.sh` fails is that the lines:

```
for l in sh rb py php java cs; do
  (cd $l; ./run-tests.sh)
done
```

for a compound statement. The status of this compound statement is the status of the last run of `./run-tests.sh`.

Your work around sounds good to me.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't think of it as a single compound statement, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have comment rights, so posting here. It depends on the script in run-tests.sh. Are you sure this gives a non-zero value:

> ./run-tests.sh
>
> echo $?

Comment: Positive.  Hand-coded exit 1 statement for testing purposes.